# I want to add the same cardView of my xml underneath the first one when i clic on the add Button and that can be maked endlessly

Tags: android, button, cardview

Hello i'm stcuk by a little problem,
I want to add a new CardView with same set of the first CardView underneath the first Cardview only when i click on my button and this action can be repetable endlessly.
Because i'm beginner in android and i have litterally no idea how to make that.
If anyone can Copy Past this code and help me i will be very happy.
I know the spinner is void but its for after i just want to duplicate this.

my activity :

```
package com.example.lif.test;

public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner idSpinnerLance;
EditText idEdtTempsLance;
TextView idTextViewPuissance, textViewTitre;
Button idButtonAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    idSpinnerLance = findViewById(R.id.idSpinnerLance);
    idEdtTempsLance = findViewById(R.id.idEdtTempsLance);
    textViewTitre = findViewById(R.id.textViewTitre);
    idTextViewPuissance = findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPuissance);
    idButtonAdd = findViewById(R.id.idButtonAdd);

    idButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
        }
    });
}
}
```

and my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".test.testActivity">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ajouter une lance :"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/idSpinnerLance"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temps :"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtTempsLance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idButtonAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If those `CardView` will contain different data you can use a `RecyclerView` and on button click you can add an item in the list and notify the adapter this will add a new item(here item is your `CardView` created in a different XML file) on screen.

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) could be helpful
and [this](https://medium.com/swlh/android-recyclerview-part-1-creating-a-simple-list-d84392c268b0) too